# Should my script die if LDAP search fails?

Tags: perl, ldap

When I preform an LDAP search like so

```
my $mesg = $ldap->search(
base => "$dn",
scope => 'base',
filter => '(objectClass=*)',
attrs => ['member'],
);
```

Should my script just log if `$mesg->{resultCode}` is not zero, or should by script log and `die` on not zero?

Comment: That depends totally on the context in which this is running.  If an LDAP failure means your script can't continue meaningfully, then it should probably terminate.  If it can do meaningful work after an LDAP failure, then log and continue.  Nobody here can make that decision based only on what you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely up to the intended flow of your program - there isn't a general "should" or "should not".

If the code that follows depends on the search and is meaningless without it, you may die, otherwise you may skip the error and try to recover somehow.

One of the Unix principles, however, suggests that generally a program should fail as early as possible:

[Rule of Repair: When you must fail, fail noisily and as soon as possible.](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are result codes from LDAP search requests that are non-zero, yet do not indicate failure. Time limit exceeded and size limit exceeded are two examples where search results are returned, yet the result code is non-zero.